# Should asking for tool suggestions be considered on-topic?

Tags: discussion, on-topic-definition, off-topic, list-question

I've seen a number of these but [here's](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/54096/are-there-any-tools-for-writing-wiktionary-articles) just one example. The gist is, someone asks "what are some tools that do X?" X is usually a task related to writing.

In the [don't ask](https://writing.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) section it says not to ask questions where "every answer is equally valid: “What’s your favorite ______?”" This sounds an awful lot like that.

On the other hand, I could plausibly see it being possible that someone else could get value out of reading the answers to a question like this.

The "[on topic](https://writing.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)" section also says that questions about specialized writing tools are ok, but this isn't so much ABOUT a specialized writing tool as it is asking for suggestions.

Answer (score 3):

I think there's a subtle distinction to be made here. The linked question asks (emphasis mine):

> Are there **any** tools for writing Wiktionary articles?

I don't see this as asking "what's your *favourite* tool that does this", or "what's the *best* tool that does this", which would indeed be subjective. I see this as asking "does a tool that can do this *actually exist*", which can be objectively answered with, "Yes, it's called Acme Editor. [description of the software]", or, "Yes, there's a whole bunch of them: [list of descriptions]".

There's still, admittedly, an element of subjectivity to these questions, but I'd say they fall under ["good subjective" rather than "bad subjective"](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/09/29/good-subjective-bad-subjective/). Answers can be backed up with descriptions of the software's features, ease-of-use, cost, etc - all based on facts and/or user expertise, rather than just opinions.

At present, these sorts of "Are they any tools that can do this" questions are explicitly on-topic under the [software](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/software) tag (again, emphasis mine):

> Computer programs intended for writers. Questions involving the use of particular programs, or **requesting recommendation for software that will help in a particular task.**

As for whether we *should* allow them, one criterion that's been [used here in the past](https://writing.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1906/23927) when deciding scope is "How many questions of this type are we actually getting?" If we were getting snowed under by "Give me a tool that does X" questions, and users were getting noticeably sick of them, then I do think it would be worth re-evaluating whether we wanted them. But having checked the tag, we've only had seven of them since the start of 2021, so I think they're infrequent enough not to be a burden.